# selenium RC reports time outs as errors?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I ran a script using Selenium RC 1.0.3 in Firefox and the the test runner screen reports the time outs as failures. Why?

```
* info(1302097309872): Executing: |waitForTextPresent | Remote | |
* warn(1302097339885): currentTest.recordFailure: Timed out after 30000ms
```

Aren't these not supposed to be failures?

Comment: b/w Could you commit to Selenium Proposal at - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium This proposal is backed by SeleniumHQ

Answer (score 0):

The failure is because Selenium could not find text "Remote" after 30000ms. Do you see text "Remote" on your page after 30000ms?

Comment: YEs the test remote is there on the page, it just basically timeout after the default, I think. Probably I should use assertTextPresent.?

Comment: well, the funny thing I noticed was, even a typeandwait command , after 30 second time out is recorded as a failure. why? I dont get it